# How to get a list of file extensions for a general file type?

Tags: python, iterator, mime-types

I am trying to get a list of file extensions based upon the first part of a MIME type using the mimetypes module. eg. 'image' is the first part of 'image/jpeg', 'image/png' etc.

This is my code:

```
import mimetypes

def get_extensions_for_type(general_type):
    for ext in mimetypes.types_map:
        if mimetypes.types_map[ext].split('/')[0] == general_type:
            yield ext

VIDEO = tuple(get_extensions_for_type('video'))
AUDIO = tuple(get_extensions_for_type('audio'))
IMAGE = tuple(get_extensions_for_type('image'))

print("VIDEO = " + str(VIDEO))
print('')
print("AUDIO = " + str(AUDIO))
print('')
print("IMAGE = " + str(IMAGE))
```

and this is the output:

```
VIDEO = ('.m1v', '.mpeg', '.mov', '.qt', '.mpa', '.mpg', '.mpe', '.avi', '.movie', '.mp4')

AUDIO = ('.ra', '.aif', '.aiff', '.aifc', '.wav', '.au', '.snd', '.mp3', '.mp2')

IMAGE = ('.ras', '.xwd', '.bmp', '.jpe', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.xpm', '.ief', '.pbm', '.tif', '.gif', '.ppm', '.xbm', '.tiff', '.rgb', '.pgm', '.png', '.pnm')
```

This is missing a lot of formats, eg. '.flac' for audio. `mimetypes.types_map['.flac'].split('/')[0]` returns 'audio', so why is this not included in the output?

Comment: Which version of Python? I've tried both 2.6 and 3.1 and mimetypes.types_map does not contain '.flac'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution:

use:

```
mimetypes.init()
```

after importing the module.

This reads additional mime types from the operating system. ([see python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.init))

Comment: docs explain what `init` does: http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.init